# Number of Constraints in Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming

I have recently learnt in lectures that there are three defining characteristic to a linear program:

1. There must be an objective function to be maximised or minimised.
2. There must be a system of linear constraints.
3. The variables in the system must be non-negative.

My question is, is there a limit on the number of constraints that must be present for the system to be a linear program, or can there be as few as one constraint?

My initial thought was that you would need as many constrains as you do variables in order to construct a feasible region, but the lecture slides don't talk on a minimum requirement for the number of constraints in the system.

Comment: (1) The objective must also be linear (3) This is only needed for textbook algorithms. In general, LPs can have variables that are free or have lower- and/or upper bounds. Yes, there can be only one constraint (a well-known example is the knapsack problem).

Comment: Totally agree with @Erwin Kalvelagen! Only the most generally used [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) needs binary variables and is thus not a linear program. And even it's linear relaxation would still require lower and upper bounds for each of the variables. From the definition of an LP there could be no constraints at all - although problems tend to get unbounded then. And your condition (3) is required for the canonical form of an LP (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)).